# Lectura de array con json post

Tags: php, json

Recibo un `array` de tamaño (1) enviado por `POST` de un `JSON`:

```
Array
(
    [{
        "promotion": {
            "name": "PRUEBAS_|_NO_BORRAR",
            "subdomain": "pruebas"
        },
        "playNumber": 9,
        "playData": {
            "code": "3MBY9P",
            "email": "cruiz@po_es",
            "NOMBRE": "Carlos_ruizs"
        },
        "prize": "NO_PREMIO",
        "device": "Macintosh",
        "platform": "OS_X",
        "browser": "Firefox",
        "ip": "62_117_146_31",
        "playDateTime": "2017-03-21_12:52:36"
    }] => 
)
```

He intentado recorrerlo de de todas la maneras. También he realizado hacer un `decode` del `array` parámetro recibido, pero sigue teniendo el mismo formato:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($json), true, 512);
```

Para recorrerlo he intentado:

```
foreach ($array as $indice => $valor) {
      echo $indice;
      var_dump($valor);
}
```

Pero sin resultado. ¿Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo?

---

También intenté:

```
 $array=json_decode($json, true);
```

pero Apache me da esta respuesta

> : Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Y lo he intentado así (Apache no se queja, pero no obtengo nada)

```
$array= json_decode(json_encode($json),true));
```

Comment: el Array que has colocado en tu pregunta, esta mal escrito, agrega el Array correctamente, de otra forma no se te puede apoyar.

Comment: Lo he intentado ,

 $array=json_decode($json, true);
pero el apache me da esta respuesta

: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
Tambien lo he intentado asi , El apache no se queja , pero no obtego nada

$array= json_decode(json_encode($json),true));

gracias

Comment: La flecha final que aparece al final de tu array (`=>`) no tiene nada que hacer ahí. Si lo que estamos viendo es la salida de un `print_r` o un `var_dump` no te puede estar mostrando eso. ¿Qué significa que quieres "recorrerlo"? ¿Neceistas el valor de una llave en particular? ¿Lo que vemos en tu pregunta es la salida de `var_dump($valor)`?

Comment: Miguel Tabernero, agrega correctamente el Array que deseas iterar.

Answer (score 0):

Si te llega como cadena, toca hacerle el decode con el segundo parámetro en  `true` para que te lo convierta a array, si no, te los hará objetos (stdClass)

[Inténtalo aquí](http://phptester.net/)

```
<?php

$json = '[{
    "promotion": {
        "name": "PRUEBAS_|_NO_BORRAR",
        "subdomain": "pruebas"
    },
    "playNumber": 9,
    "playData": {
        "code": "3MBY9P",
        "email": "cruiz@po_es",
        "NOMBRE": "Carlos_ruizs"
    },
    "prize": "NO_PREMIO",
    "device": "Macintosh",
    "platform": "OS_X",
    "browser": "Firefox",
    "ip": "62_117_146_31",
    "playDateTime": "2017-03-21_12:52:36"
}]';

$resultado = '';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ( $arr as $k ) {

    foreach ( $k as $indice => $valor ) {

        if ( is_array($valor) ) {
            foreach ( $valor as $j => $ivalor ) {
                $resultado .= "$indice [$j] = $ivalor <br>";
            }
        } else {
            $resultado .= "$indice: $valor <br>";
        }
    }    
}

echo $resultado;
```